# CUPS проблемы с печатью

Tags: печать, debian

Привет!

3 принтера подключены к cups. К примеру p1, p2, p3 Печать идет сразу на 3 принтера (обычной командой lp) Время от времени появляются вот такие проблемы:

p1 - печатает нормально p2 - "Pause: Unable to send data..." p3 - "Process: Waiting for printer to become available"

или

p1 - "Pause: Unable to send data..." p2 - печатает нормально p3 - "Process: Waiting for printer to become available"

p1 - "Pause: Unable to send data..." p2 - "Pause: Unable to send data..." p3 - "Process: Waiting for printer to become available"

или

p1 - "Pause: Unable to send data..." p2 - печатает нормально p3 - печатает нормально

если принтеру, который ответил "pause. unable.." дать команду - Resume Printer - начинает печатать.

а вот 3й принтер ведет себя еще более странно - он иногда уходит в спящий режим, и если подан документ на печать - он его не распечатает, пока не разбудишь его кнопкой "ок" на корпусе

Что это может быть? Как обеспечить стабильность печати?

p.s.: p1 и p2 - одинаковые принтеры, kyoceгa p3 - тоже kyoceгa, но другая модель подключены через usb OS Debian 7

Comment: есть идеи?

Comment: Для кого интиересно - решилось переустановкой с Debian на Ubuntu. Скорее всего проблема с драйверами и на убунте все встало хорошо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для кого интиересно - решилось переустановкой с Debian на Ubuntu. Скорее всего проблема с драйверами и на убунте все встало хорошо